# Is is possible to write time_bucket_gapfill alternative in plpgsql

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series, plpgsql

i currently have a bunch of event in a recent postgresql database, 
and i would like to query them say number of event per month where...

and i would like "fill" the dates gaps like if there are no events , i would like to still have a row.

I can currently do this with bunch of generate series, then left join with my data, then again coalesce all my columns...
i doesn't look really pretty and it's kinda hard to read (and generate).

i stumble upon the time_bucket_gapfill of timescale, and found it very nice, 
i was wondering if it's possible to write it down in plpgsql or it's specific to the extension.
I know i can do a function that can return a set of, but not really sure how to begin

or is there a neater alternative than

```sql
SELECT
    coalesce(start, tick)::date,
    coalesce(x, 0),
    coalesce(y, 0)
FROM ( select generate_series('2020-01-01'::date, now()::date,'1 day'::interval) as tick, 0,0 ) AS ticks

    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            date_trunc('day', created) AS START,
            count(*) FILTER (WHERE TYPE = 'X') AS X,
            count(*) FILTER (WHERE TYPE = 'Y') AS Y FROM events WHERE column='test'
                AND TYPE in('X', 'Y')
                AND created >= '2020-01-01'
                AND created <= now()
            GROUP BY
    1) AS ts

    on ticks.tick = ts.start
;
```

Thanks for the help

Example of expected data :

```
2020-03-01 00:00:00 0   0
2020-04-01 00:00:00 0   0
2020-05-01 00:00:00 12234   28171
```

Answer (score 1):

The Postgres method doesn't seem so cumbersome:

```
select gs.yyyymm,
       count(*) filter (e.type = 'X') as num_xs,
       count(*) filter (e.type = 'Y') as num_ys
from generate_series('2019-01-01'::date, '2019-12-01':date, interval '1 month'
                    ) gs(yyyymm) left join
     events e
     on e.column = 'test' and
        e.type in ('X', 'Y') and
        e.created >= gs.yyyymm and
        e.created < gs.yyyymm + interval '1 month'
group by gs.yyyymm
order by gs.yyyymm;
```

This doesn't seem particularly complicated.  I don't really see how wrapping it in a function would simplify it very much.

Comment: ARG thanks i forgot the "on" way of doing it /o\ shame.

anyway, you could avoid the join part ... not A LOT nicer, but still nicer...
(still interested by the response, like is it possible)